# Give a definition of a function in three rows - aligned

Tags: math-mode, align, alignat, alignment

How could I make this into a tex code? I already tried with alignat{2} but I have not got any good-looking-result.

My attempt:

```
\begin{alignat*}{4}
f:A&\to\mathrm{Aut}(A)&&&&\\
a&\mapsto\tilde{a}:B\to B,~&&b&&\mapsto a(b)&
\\&&&c&&\mapsto c&&
\end{alignat*}
```

But I don't know how to insert the brackets.

[image]

Comment: Aligned will work just fine here. But we are not a _do this for me_ service, please show whatever code you have so far.

Comment: If you had tried `alignat` but found it unsatisfactory, you could still post your code so everyone would understand your effort. ;-)

Comment: Done :) .......

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is to use as many alignment tabs `&` as you need. The command `\deffunctionfull` takes care of the *formatting of function definition*. The syntax is as follows:

```
\deffunctionfull[<output>]{<function name>}{<domain>}{<range>}{<input>}
```

The `<output>` is optional: When not used, it automatically pieces `<function name>(<input>)`. But you can be creative to come up with your own `<output>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\deffunctionfull[5][\default@functionoutput]{%
  \def\default@functionoutput{#2(#5)}%
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}l@{}}
  #2\colon#3 & {}\to#4 \\
          #5 & {}\mapsto#1
  \end{array}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
&\deffunctionfull{f}{A}{\Aut(A)}{a} \\[1ex]
&\deffunctionfull[{\begin{bmatrix}
                   \tilde{a}\colon A\to A, & b\mapsto a(b)\\
                                           & c\mapsto c
                   \end{bmatrix}}]{f}{A}{\Aut(A)}{a} \\[1ex]
&\deffunctionfull[{\left[\begin{aligned}
                   \tilde{a}\colon A\to A, \quad b &\mapsto a(b)\\
                                                 c &\mapsto c
                   \end{aligned}\right]}]{f}{A}{\Aut(A)}{a} \\[1ex]
&\deffunctionfull[{\left[\begin{alignedat}{4}
                   &\tilde{a}\colon A &&\to AB, \quad &&ab &&\mapsto a(b)\\
                   &\text{anything}   &&\to A,        &&c  &&\mapsto c
                   \end{alignedat}\right]}]{f}{A}{\Aut(A)}{a}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: define function]

Comment: Thank you! In the picture on the right the b and c are not in a column. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Super, now image I don't want c\mapsto c but ab\mapsto c. If I replace this, the b and ab are aligned on the right. Is it possible to get them on the left?

Comment: I mean align at the symbold AND the arrows. Don't know if thats possible.

Comment: @user114179 I think my newest update gives what you want.